# SQL to link latest progress update to a project record in an interactive report Oracle APEX

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I am creating a project database for my team. Each project is housed in a table named PROJECT, and I have a separate table named PROGRESSUPDATES to track any progress a users adds to their project.

I want to display the latest update for each project in an interactive report.

A sample of the data is:

PROJECTS:

```
id | NAME             | Description | Status
______________________
1  | Project 1        | abc         | On Track
2  | Project 2        | def         | On Hold
3  | Project 3        | ghi         | Completed
4  | Project 4        | jkl         | Cancelled
5  | Project 5        | mno         | On Track
```

PROGRESSUPDATES:

```
id | NAME             | Update             | Date
______________________
1  | Project 1        | Update 1 of 3      | 04-APR-16 11.29.00.000000 AM
1  | Project 1        | Update 2 of 3      | 05-APR-16 11.29.00.000000 AM
1  | Project 1        | Update 3 of 3      | 10-APR-16 11.29.00.000000 AM
4  | Project 4        | Update for P4      | 29-MAR-16 01.30.00.000000 PM
4  | Project 4        | New Update for P4  | 05-APR-16 01.30.00.000000 PM
5  | Project 5        | Update for P5      | 05-APR-16 11.47.00.000000 AM
```

### Desired result:

```
id | NAME             | Description | Status     | Latest Update
______________________
1  | Project 1        | abc         | On Track   | Update 3 of 3
2  | Project 2        | def         | On Hold    | No update found.
3  | Project 3        | ghi         | Completed  | No update found.
4  | Project 4        | jkl         | Cancelled  | New update for P4
5  | Project 5        | mno         | On Track   | Update for P5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get this solved by some colleagues at work, and wanted to share the code in case it helps someone else.

```
SELECT a.* from (
select 
ID,
NAME,
DESCRIPTION,
STATUS,
UPDATE AS "Latest Update",
DATE AS "Update Date",
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PROJECTS.ID ORDER BY DATE DESC) AS RN
from   "PROJECTS"
LEFT outer join PROGRESSUPDATES
ON PROJECTS.ID = PROGRESSUPDATES.ID
)a
WHERE a.RN =1
```